# JavaScript exponent in Number literal confusion

Tags: javascript, exponent

Maybe time for another coffee, but I am seeing a strange issue that I wasn't expecting to see.

I'm reading JavaScript The Good Parts and in the grammar section I am seeing the following:

> If a number literal has an exponent part, then the value of the
>   literal is computed by multiplying the part before the e by 10 raised
>   to the power of the part after the e. So 100 and 1e2 are the same
>   number.
>
> From pg. 8 of 
>   JavaScript: The Good Parts by Douglas Crockford. Copyright 2008 Yahoo! Inc., 978-0-596-51774-8.

I'm I incorrect in thinking that 2e2 should equal 400?

According to the book, shouldn't this value be (2*10)^2?

In my console it is showing me 2e2 == 200.. Is my math, reading comprehension, or anything else off? Do I need to return to basic algebra?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It should be 2 * (10^2)

Comment: `2e2` = `2*10^2` - standard [scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E-notation)

Comment: @VLAZ is it just me, or does the book read incorrectly to you as well? 

Order of operations (at least from what I am reading from this section) would be to take the 2 (from the left of 'e') and multiple that by 10 then raise that to the part after the e...? I am assuming that I need to just review scientific notation?

Comment: @user2879041 no, it's absolutely correct. As I said, `2e2` = `2*10^2`. The order of operations is power first, then multiplication.

Comment: fair enough. gonna close the question. reading is difficult

Comment: I was reading his sentence more along the lines of step by step (& PEMDAS), rather than the whole equation at once. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`2e2` is interpreted as `2*(10^2)` and not `(2*10)^2`. The former evaluates to `2 * 100` which equals 200. The latter evaluates to `20 ^ 2` which is why you are getting 400.

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't help that the book's only example evaluates to 100 in both scenarios (1e2)

Answer (score 0):

Here part before e is 2.
Part after e is 2.
10 raised to the power of the part after the e = Math.pow(10,2) is 100
So  multiplying the part before the e by 10 raised to the power of the part after the e is `2*Math.pow(10,2) = 200.`